# Rock Paper Scissors Not Printing Out Results

Tags: python

I am trying to create a Rock Paper Scissors program against a computer but running into some issues.

I have made two methods, one for the computer's choice and the user's choice. For the computer, it randomly generates 0,1,2 and selects rock, paper or scissors from an array which I declared as a local variable, `rps`. When I try to run the game with the `game_play()` method, I am able to enter in input but don't get an output of the result between the player and the computer.

```
class RockPaperScissors():
    global rps
    rps = ['rock', 'paper','scissors']

    def computer_choice(self): #computer randomly picks rock paper or scissors
        x = random.randint(0,2)
        w = rps[x]
        return w
        #print(rps[x])

    def player_choice(self): #does the player choose rock paper or scissors
        x = True 
        while x:
            choice = (input("Player- would you like rock, paper, or scissors? enter rock,paper, or scissors?: "))
            if choice.lower() == 'rock':
                    return 'rock'
            elif choice.lower() == 'paper':
                    return 'paper'
            elif choice.lower() == 'scissors':
                    return 'scissors'
            else:
                ("please enter in rock, paper or scissors")

    def game_play(self):
        rock = RockPaperScissors()
        user = rock.player_choice()
        comp= rock.computer_choice()

        if comp == 'rock' and user == 'paper':
            return "the player wins!"
        elif comp == 'rock' and user == 'scissors':
            return "the computer wins!"
        elif comp == 'paper' and user == 'rock':
            return "the computer wins!"
        elif comp == 'paper' and user == 'scissors':
            return "the player wins!"
        elif comp == 'scissors' and user == 'paper':                        
            return"the computer wins!"
        elif comp == 'scissors' and user == 'rock':
            return "the player wins"
```

I am trying to test it this way:

```
rock = RockPaperScissors()
rock.game_play()
```

Comment: What happens when both comp and user pick the same? You need more `elif` or an `else` to catch when it's a draw... Also nowhere in your code do I see a print, which is why there's no output

Comment: I first noticed that your game_play function instantiates another instance of the object you call "rock" rather than uses the one in your test code.  I suggesting taking out rock=RockPaperScissors() from your game_play function and for the variables user and comp use self.player_choice(), etc.

Comment: I believe Tyler is correct.  I gave your code several attempts and got back nothing but eventually did get back an object. (which you will want to print to screen).  I just assumed that all the times I was getting nothing was when it was being tied.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum that makes sense.  The interactive shell won't print anything when a function returns `None`, which it will when it reaches the end of the function without a `return`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running it as a script instead of everything in the Python interpreter. You must explicitly print the value.

One possible solution is:

```py
rock = RockPaperScissors()
print(rock.game_play())
```

Answer (score 1):

Directly answering your question: you are not "printing" the game, which would be...

```
print(rock.game_play())
```

However, there's some other improvements I would do.

- Avoid global variables so that you can provide greater clarity to
  the code. Maybe it's a better idea to define rps inside the function
  computer_choice() instead of having it as a global variable.
- You can simplify player_choice() as:

```
x = input("Player- would you like rock, paper, or scissors? enter rock,paper, or scissors?: ").lower()
while x != 'rock' and x != 'paper' and x != 'scissors':
    choice = (input("Player- would you like rock, paper, or scissors? enter rock, paper, or scissors?: "))  
    x = input("please enter in rock, paper or scissors").lower()
return x
```

- Possibly, your code wasn't copied correctly, but everything below the first line (class RockPaperScissors:) is missing one indent.

Finally, another possible solution is to print the game's result inside function game_play() instead of returning a string.

Good luck and keep learning.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about most of your issues but I do know you to use a print statement for any text to appear on the screen

```
print('this code for example will print the text within the parentheses and the single quotation marks')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).